# Saving markers to map in app crashes with "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method"

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I am trying to save markers to my app when users tap on the map.  Previously I uses a different method of doing this, (using eclipse) but have since moved on to android studio and for some weird reason that code doesn't work crashes when app launch.  I have also asked a question on SO (thanks to all that helped) but wasn't successful. So I was advised to use a different method, so have decided to use SQLite database.

So this is what I am sitting with now:

```
24434-24434/com.new.newapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.new.newapp, PID: 24434
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap.onViewCreated(FragmentGoogleMap.java:109)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

So here is my code:

FragmentGoogleMap class:

```
Context context = getActivity();
MarkerDataSource Mdata;
MyMarkerObj Mobj;
static final  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
boolean dbCheckedOpen = false;

.....

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Mdata = new MarkerDataSource(context);
    Mobj = new MyMarkerObj();

    try {
        Mdata.open();
        dbCheckedOpen = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

//LINE 109 -->// Cursor cursor = Mdata.db.query(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, Mdata.cols, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {

        List<MyMarkerObj> mmo = Mdata.getMarkers();
        for (int i = 0; i < mmo.size(); i++)
        {
            String latidutes = mmo.get(i).getLat().toString();
            String langidutes = mmo.get(i).getLng().toString();
            LatLng latlngs = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitudes), Double.valueOf(longitudes));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(mmo.get(i).getTitle().toString())
                    .snippet(mmo.get(i).getSnippet().toString())
                    .position(latlngs));
        }
    }

 }

.....

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
    if (dbCheckedOpen == false)
    {
        try {
            Mdata.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Take Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            EditText title = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ettitle);
            EditText snippet = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etsnippet);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(title.getText().toString())
                    .snippet(snippet.getText().toString())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                    .position(point));
            markerId = marker.getId();

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Images");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "MyMarkerImages_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);

            Mobj.setLat(String.valueOf(point.latitude));
            Mobj.setLng(String.valueOf(point.longitude));
            Mobj.setZom(String.valueOf(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));
            Mobj.setTitle(String.valueOf(title.getText()));
            Mobj.setSnippet(String.valueOf(snippet.getText()));
            Mobj.setImage(String.valueOf(markerId));
            Mobj.setFilepath(String.valueOf(image.getAbsolutePath()));

            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, Mobj.getLat());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, Mobj.getLng());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOM, Mobj.getZom());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_TITLE, Mobj.getTitle());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_SNIP, Mobj.getSnippet());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE, Mobj.getImage());
            contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, Mobj.getFilepath ());
```

Locations DB Class:

```
public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/** Database name */
private static final String DBNAME  = "markerlocations.db";

/** Version number of the database */
private static final int    VERSION = 1;
public static final String  FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String  FIELD_LAT  = "lat";
public static final String  FIELD_LNG  = "lng";
public static final String  FIELD_ZOM  = "zom";
public static final String  FIELD_TITLE  = "title";
public static final String  FIELD_SNIP = "snip";
public static final String  FIELD_IMAGE = "img";
public static final String  FIELD_FILEPATH = "filep";

/** A constant, stores the the table name */
public static final String  DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";
public static final String  DB_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
        FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
        FIELD_LNG + " text , " +
        FIELD_LAT + " text , " +
        FIELD_ZOM + " text , " +
        FIELD_TITLE + " text , " +
        FIELD_SNIP + " text , " +
        FIELD_IMAGE + " blob , " +
        FIELD_FILEPATH + "text , " +
        " ) ";


/** Constructor */
public LocationsDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (db == null) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

MarkerDataSource Class

```
public class MarkerDataSource {

LocationsDB mDB;
SQLiteDatabase db;
final String[] cols = {
        LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOM,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_TITLE,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_SNIP,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE,
        LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH };

FragmentGoogleMap main;


public MarkerDataSource(Context C) {

    mDB = new LocationsDB(C);

}


public void open() throws SQLException
{
    db = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
}


public void close()
{
    db.close();
}


public void addMarker()
{
    main = new FragmentGoogleMap();
    db.insert(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, null, main.contentValues);
}


public List<MyMarkerObj> getMarkers() {
    List<MyMarkerObj> markers = new ArrayList<MyMarkerObj>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(LocationsDB.DATABASE_TABLE, cols, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while ( !cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        MyMarkerObj mmo = cursorToMarker(cursor);
        markers.add(mmo);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return markers;
}


private MyMarkerObj cursorToMarker(Cursor cursor) {
    MyMarkerObj mmo = new MyMarkerObj();
    mmo.setLat(cursor.getString(0));
    mmo.setLng(cursor.getString(1));
    mmo.setZom(cursor.getString(2));
    mmo.setTitle(cursor.getString(3));
    mmo.setSnippet(cursor.getString(4));
    mmo.setFilepath(cursor.getString(5));
    mmo.setLng(cursor.getString(1));
    return mmo;
}
```

MyMarkerObj Class

```
public class MyMarkerObj {

private Long   id;
private String lat;
private String lng;
private String zom;
private String title;
private String snip;
private String image;
private String filep;



public MyMarkerObj() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public MyMarkerObj(Long id, String lat, String lng, String zom, String title, String snip, String img, String filep)
{
    this.setId(id);
    this.setLat(lat);
    this.setLng(lng);
    this.setZom(zom);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setSnippet(snip);
    this.setImage(img);
    this.setFilepath(filep);

}


public MyMarkerObj(String lat, String lng, String zom, String title, String snip, String img, String filep)
{
    this.setLat(lat);
    this.setLng(lng);
    this.setZom(zom);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setSnippet(snip);
    this.setImage(img);
    this.setFilepath(filep);
}

//ID
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

//Latitude
public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}
public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

//Longitude
public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}
 public void setLng(String lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

//Zoom
public String getZom() {
    return zom;
}
public void setZom(String zom) {
    this.zom = zom;
}

//Title
public String getTitle() {
    return zom;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

//Snippet
public String getSnippet() {
    return zom;
}
public void setSnippet(String snip) {
    this.snip = snip;
}

//File Path
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

//File Path
public String getFilepath() {
    return filep;
}
public void setFilepath(String filep) {
    this.filep = filep;
}
```

I am really sorry for all the code, but am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T SWALLOW EXCEPTIONS!**

You do:

```
try {
    Mdata.open();
    dbCheckedOpen = true;
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

and assume the database opened correctly, without even a log message. At a latter stage, an error that implies that implies that there was indeed an error and `MarkerDataSource.db` points a null reference happens...

**If you get an exception thrown at it, you either know how to handle it (and do handle it that way), or log it and crash the program/module in an user-friendly way**

Check the exception you are getting whe nopening the DB, try to solve it or poste it here (as a different question, because this is already answered).